# Eclipse resolving symbols but, not the "right" ones. How to exclude certain directories from index?

Tags: c, eclipse, indexing, resolution, symbols

I am working with a HUGE code base, developed by a LOT of people. The code contains code for, lets say, multiple targets. I am working on Target L. Target specific codes are in individual directories.

During compile time, based on certain flags, the code is selectively compiled. No problems at all.

However, when I am working with the code for target L, and when I try to resolve / follow a function or a variable or a literal or anything, sometimes eclipse leads me to the declaration / function from a different target.

Ex: I follow a variable xyz and it opens up the declaration from target S instead of the target of my interest, L. Per my description above, xyz will appear in code sections of multiple target specific code.

I guess it is going to the first or last declaration it found when building the index. My guess is, its taking me to the last declaration it found when building index.

My question is, can I exclude certain directories from the eclipse code index?

I tried excluding the directories from my working set, but that didnt help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try setting the same defines the build system uses to build a particular target. That should better match what gets compiled anyway.

**Edit:**
You can also select all items (deselect desired items), right-click, select Resource Configurations -> Exclude from Build. Then rebuild the index.

Comment: though that sounds reasonable and probably might work, it is impossible for me to set those in Eclipse. Those are set by autoconf during compile time. And there are way too many to list accurately. In my case, it is not practical.

Comment: I wouldn't expect the autoconf generated output to change much on a specific system unless the system changes. Doesn't autoconf generate it's own header with what it finds? Also checkout the "-E -dM" options of gcc to generate the defines in a separate header you can use only for Eclipse.

Comment: let me rephrase the question - "I want to exclude certain directories from the index." period.

Comment: I suggested the defines because it's more "accurate" in matching what gets compiled. But if you're sure the second option works as you expect, great.

Comment: Yeah, the defines is not practical in my case. The code has 100s of directories and each directory has a different set of defs. And the number of defs per directory can be in 10s. so when I said its not practical, i did mean it was not practical. :)

Comment: I'm not sure how your autoconf is configured, but normally, it produces a config.h that each project includes to use the proper defines as determined by autoconf. I don't know how you set any of your other project specific defines, but maybe you can use autoconf to include them in that same header during build, rather than just the command line. They must exist somewhere to build, you just need to save them.

Comment: I tried Exclude from build before, but nothing happened. Thanks for your Rebuild index tip - this way it works!